# How do you assign one series to another or merge where index does not intersect and retain values from one of the series for the interesting indices

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have

```
S1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
S2 = pd.Series([5,6,7,8], index = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

I want to get

```
S3 = pd.Series([1,2,5,6,7,8], index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

If an index is in `S1` but not `S2` keep value in `S1`. If index is not in `S1` but is in `S2` keep value in `S2`. if index in in both `S1` and `S2` keep value in `S2`.

It can also be viewed as a merge of `S1` and `S2` but for the values where the index interests keep the values in `S2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) if all output values are integers:

```
S3 = S2.combine_first(S1).astype(int)
print (S3)
A    1
B    2
C    5
D    6
E    7
F    8
dtype: int32
```